Kotlin Notebooks: How to replace null values with values based on another column
Say I have the dataframe like this:
val df = dataFrameOf("name", "age")(
    "Alice", 15,
    "Bob", 20,
    null, 100
)

Then I want to replace null in the name columns with the age column (the third row would be: 100, 100).
Ideally, I'd like this to work, but it doesn't:
df.fillNulls { it["name"] }.with { it["age"] }

Apparently, I can't use it in with function.
mapToColumn kind of works, but drops all other columns:
df.mapToColumn("name") { it["name"] ?: it["age"] }

How can I just remap the null values to values from another column? I love Kotlin Dataframe, but some things seem not easy doing with it.

if you create column accessors, you should be able to reference them directly in the fillNulls call.

Thanks, figured it out and added the full example.

With the hint from AlexT, it's done like this:
val age by column<Int>()
df.fillNulls { it["name"] }.with { age.toString() }

